# Document Set custom content type - welcome page missing

Tags: content-type, document-set

Sharepoint 2013. 404 error on welcome page for a following content type based on document set:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{B9B7D98D-A2D3-4191-9B30-C516C8EDD9F4}" DisplayName="Fieldpr41" Name="Fieldpr41" Type="Note" RichText="false" NumLines="3" Group="pr41" Overwrite="TRUE" />

  <!-- Parent ContentType: Document Set (0x0120D520) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x0120D5200062FEFD4873814585B3EFD57010F1F8AE"
               Name="ContentType41"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="My Content Type"
               Inherits="FALSE"
               ProgId="SharePoint.DocumentSet"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{B9B7D98D-A2D3-4191-9B30-C516C8EDD9F4}" DisplayName="Fieldpr41" Name="Fieldpr41" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument
    NamespaceURI=
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields">
        <wpFields:WelcomePageFields
        xmlns:wpFields=
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields"
        LastModified="1/1/2010 08:00:00 AM">
          <WelcomePageField id="83729202-DCA7-4BF8-A75B-56DDDE53189C" />
        </wpFields:WelcomePageFields>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any exception in 15 hive logs? And does everything works fine after removing this?

Comment: Nothing related in log.
If Inherits="FALSE" parameter changed to TRUE then welcome page displayed. I think I messed up with custom welcome page declaration...

Comment: Here's what i did after changing Inherits parameter to FALSE:
1) added ProgId parameter
2) added wpFields section

Comment: So is it working fine?

Comment: it works fine with enabled inheritance, but I need it to be disabled (Inherits="FALSE")

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37350/custom-sharepoint-2010-documentset-contenttype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that once you break inheritance you need to define CT completely. I've just added formurl in an feature event receiver.